# lgrind.dtx no longer compiles as of TeX Live 2020, potential problem with new latex3 core?

Tags: latex3, dtx

I originally asked this question on the tldistro mailing list (I'm the TeX Live package maintainer for OpenBSD) and Karl Berry suggested I post here.

The `lgrind.dtx` included in lgrind-3.67 no longer builds as of TeX Live 2020 (it *does* build with TeX Live 2019).

The steps to compile are:

- `latex lgrind.ins`
- `latex lgrind.dtx` (twice)

This should generate `lgrind.dvi`.

Here's what we get with TeX Live 2020:

```
$ latex lgrind.ins
... (this bit works fine)
$ latex lgrind.dtx
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020-OpenBSD_Ports) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./lgrind.dtx
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-03-06>
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltxdoc.cls
Document Class: ltxdoc 2019/09/16 v2.0y Standard LaTeX documentation class
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/doc.sty
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/multicol.sty)))
Writing index file lgrind.idx
Writing glossary file lgrind.glo
(./lgrind.dtx
(/usr/local/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.def

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.2 %% T
        his is file `l3backend-dvips.def',
```

The `T` there apparently appears in the preamble, which is what causes this error, but why? Looks like comment stripping has been over-zealous? Perhaps a bug?

(The sources for lgrind-3.67 are [here](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/support/lgrind/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The source file does

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\DocInput{lgrind.dtx}
\end{document}
```

and hides the `\begin{document}` *inside* `\DocInput`. That means that `%` is not a comment char during `\begin{document}`, which messes up anything that loads additional files there. It shows up because `l3backend` is now loaded there, but really it's not 'right' anyway. The best solution is to alter the `.dtx` to

```latex
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\CodelineIndex
\RecordChanges
\begin{document}
\DocInput{lgrind.dtx}
\end{document}
```

while removing the `\begin{document}` line below

```latex
% \GetFileInfo{lgrind.dtx}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I said this on the mailing list too :)

Comment: Thanks Joseph. I'll give this a shot when I get a moment. I must have missed the post on the mailing list -- at least the only reply I see to my thread is from Karl.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. That works!